# What addons are available for keeping up Buffs in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I would like to find a *very simple* addon to help my wife remember to cast her buffs. She is leveling a Priest, and could use a hand keeping up Inner Fire on herself as well as Power Word: Fortitude and Divine Spirit on the party.

I myself currently use ZOMGBuffs, but I want to look into other options before recommending one to her.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SmartBuff](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/smart-buff.aspx) has been around for at least 3 years. Always worked for me when I used to raid (as a priest but works for other classes).

Comment: Smartbuff also lets you bind "rebuff" to the mousewheel or something, so you can simply wheel the mouse to rebuff automatically.

Comment: Correct, that’s how I used to do it, until I had to change my mouse because the wheel stopped working properly. Priest -> 3 group buffs + 2 self buffs.

Comment: I tried several of these, and SmartBuff was the least annoying while being easy to use..

Answer (score 2):

[AnnoyingBuffReminder](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/annoying-buff-reminder.aspx). As the name says, it's annoying and will learn her to buff everyone / herself the hard way :)

Comment: I don't think this addon has been updated for Cata. Too bad, it was a good one.

Answer (score 1):

If she plans to do any healing, [VuhDo](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/vuhdo.aspx) has a lot of panels and options.  One of these is the "BuffWatch", in which she can choose any buff and an indicator will show up here when it is missing from herself or a party member.

I have mine set to turn off all panels except BuffWatch when I'm not in a party.

Answer (score 1):

For your own buffs, AnnoyingBuffReminder is great, like Ondrej posted. I don't think it does Power word: Shield, but it does all the other priest buffs.

If you want to check your entire raid for buffs, I'd recommend [RaidBuffStatus](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/raidbuffstatus.aspx). You can use it for your own buffs as well, but I feel it's a little too complicated when you use it just for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of ZOMGBuffs personally.  I've done a few others, but I like the overall feel of it, plus the mousewheel buffing / rebuffing is the hotness when you're having to buff a raid as a pally. :P